# In 4 Layer PCB - which internal layer has to be consider to calculate Microstrip characteristic Independence for bottom layer

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-layers

[image: 4 layer PCB Stackup]

4-layer PCB stack-up as shown in attached figure - In case of bottom layer; which internal layer has to be considered to calculate characteristic impedance for microstrip line on that layer. Is it power plane or ground plane?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layer containing the nearest unbroken plane.

Ideally that would be the next one, because any layers in between cannot be used, or you create an impedance mismatch.

Answer (score 2):

The power plane, assuming it's intact over the microstrip with no power plane edges "close" to the microstrip conductor.

The ground layer isn't "seen" by the fields.

Comment: In another case; if power plane is broken! then is it OK to consider far ground plane as reference? Or still in that case also power plane will remain as reference?

Comment: If the microstrip crosses a break you’ll get a discontinuity in impedance, which would be bad. If the power plane is removed  under and to a “far” distance from the trace it will see only the ground plane. Both ground and power planes can be considered at ground for AC purposes. That assumes the planes are large, close together and have typical bypass capacitors in addition to the inter plane capacitance.